# Pulling data from ELM327

Tags: android

am developing an application where I can get data from ELM327 and display it on an android device.But I have a doubt,the ELM327 is not controllable,I mean it cant keep sending data automatically to the android device,so how would I be able to pull data from the ELM327.I am really stuck here.So help would be appreciated.Thank you!

---

Can anyone help me with the type of commands I have to use in android to get responses from ELM 327?How would I only receive speed and rpm?How can I read that data and display it on the android device?

Comment: ELM327 is a car diagnostic device that pulls data from the OBD of the car.http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ELM device is a command/response device which requires you to send a command in order for the ELM to process it, communicate with the ECU system, then format and deliver the response back to you. You won't get unsolicited messages (responses) from an ELM327 chip except on power up when the signature is sent, or unless you set the device into a monitor mode.

Comment: what kind of commands would those be?I mean can I use the general android commands like GET to pull the data?

Comment: Can anyone help me with the type of commands I have to use in android to get responses from ELM 327?How would I only receive speed and rpm?How can I read that data and display it on the android device?

Comment: For RPM, send "010C\r" for vehicle speed send "010D\r"

Comment: the \r is the character used for the hex value 0x0D to be sent to tell the ELM327 (or equivalent) that is the end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

The ELM327 is that you use Bluetooth.
I'm trying to make an application to read data adnroid ELM 327, you could.